# Devtools Network panel stopped working in Chrome 32?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When stable channel Chrome auto-updated to version 32, the devtools network panel suddenly started dropping network traffic.  It appears that traffic from the top-level document is shown but traffic from iframes is missing.  Reloading the last stable version (31.0.1650.63) shows all traffic, as expected.  I have no extensions loaded, just start up Chrome, open devtools network pane, go to a webpage and watch what happens.

Is there something like an `<all_frames>` setting that now needs to be set to get full coverage, or is this a regression (like the "[Page Unresponsive](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335248)" box that started popping up every 5 seconds in 32).

Edit: Screenshots from a simple demo site: playing one round of a game at [flashgames.com](http://www.flashgames.com/color-balls-solitaire)

**Chrome 31 (what you'd expect):**

[image: Chrome Stable Version 31]

**Chrome 32 (nearly blind):**

[image: Chrome Stable Version 32]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/LNbVvwwun5A/Nqga96xn3_8J):

> This is caused by http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=226031&view=revision -- "Switch to fetching NPAPI requests through the browser process instead of going through the renderer."
>
> So network requests issued by browser itself are not reported to Blink, so they do not exist from the point of view of WebApp.  See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173844

The problem appears when using the Adobe flash plugin.  It apparently is not possible both use the debug version of flash player and see its network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the record button (the circle) in the top left to make sure you're actively recording network activity.

It'll automatically record when you're refreshing the page but it'll turn off to help preserve the waterfall.

Click it to control it's behavior.